# using $elemMatch in projection with field choosing

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to select only some fields in document while also using $elemmatch. It turned out the field selection is getting ignored.

Given a document like this:

```
{
  "author": "Robin Sharma",
  "data": [
    {
      "translation": "en",
      "content": "foo",
      "unwanted_content": "huyu1",
    },
    {
      "translation": "id",
      "content": "bar",
      "unwanted_content": "huyu2",
    {
  ],
}
```

I'm using `find()` with this projection config:

```js
const projection = {
  author: 1,
  data: {
    $elemMatch: {
      translation: "en"
    },
  },
}
```

Expected

```
{
  "author": "Robin Sharma",
  "data": [
    {
      "translation": "en",
      "content": "foo"
    },
  ],
}
```

Actual

```
{
  "author": "Robin Sharma",
  "data": [
    {
      "translation": "en",
      "content": "foo",
      "unwanted_content": "huyu1",
    },
  ],
}
```

I'm still not sure how to get rid of the "unwanted_content" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your required result using aggregate as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "data.translation": "en"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$author",
      data: {
        $push: {
          translation: "$data.translation",
          content: "$data.content"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this to get only selected fields from subdocument.

```
db.collection.find({"data.translation": "en"},{author: 1, "data.content": 1, "data.translation": 1})
```